# Powershell .NET syntax

Tags: powershell

I'm reading [this](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff730951.aspx) guide to setting Windows ACLs, and I want to know how to look up options or instructions for these two lines:

```
$colRights = [System.Security.AccessControl.FileSystemRights]"Read, Write"

$objUser = New-Object System.Security.Principal.NTAccount("wingroup\kenmyer")
```

Why is the first one not in parentheses?

Comment: First is an enumeration and second is referring to class constructor. This is powershell syntax. Best to look up using basic .net from powershell. Without .NEt background it's a but more tricky, but you just need to understand the basics.

Comment: I've been searching each time I want to know how to use something, but yeah I'd need a book or something to go further. The .NET classes seem endless. Do people end up memorizing them all, or is there an easier way to do this?

Comment: You have misunderstood. The theory is that you don't need .NET classes to do PowerShell. But the reality is that some things are missing, and then you need to fallback to .NET because PowerShell is .NET. When the .NET SDK is missing, then you need to fallback to the system calls using pinvoke. Still, you don't need to know the .NET ecosystem, it just help to have a basic understanding of the .NET technology, because it helps you understand and use quickly the solutions provided by google. So to summarize, basic .net understanding helps with Powershell but it's not a prerequisite.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first statement,

```
$colRights = [System.Security.AccessControl.FileSystemRights]"Read, Write"
```

Refers to [FileSystemRights Enumeration](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.accesscontrol.filesystemrights(v=vs.110).aspx). The syntax having two enums together combines those. That is, `$colRights` will contain flags for both `Read` and `Write`.

The second , [NTAccount](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.principal.ntaccount(v=vs.110).aspx) refers to an account or security group. That is, user or group `kenmeyer`, who is located in either computer or domain `wingroup`.

As why the later is in parenthesis, it is a call for *constructor*. The first is an *enumeration* allowing bitwise combination of its member values.